# Setting text size according to overall width of superview

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uilabel

Its not really a programming question but a design implementation question but anyway im wondering how you choose the text sizes in general according to the screen size. So an example is like before there was auto layout i used to say I want this views width to always be 30% of the superviews width. So no matter on what screen, be it iPhone or iPad, the width of the view will always be 30% of its superview. Now im wondering how would you choose the text size. Whats the rule of thumb for choosing the text size of a UILabel if its going to not look good on an iPhone but will look good on an iPad. What i would really want from everyone is for us to talk about rules of thumbs we use specifically when hitting my current situation. What do you do?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all you should 
[read the HIG:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/ColorImagesText.html)

Now to add some value with interpretation, there's not inherently a different between iPad and iPhone. IF it's legible on device it should be more or less legible on another, unless you're on the cusp of being legible on the lowest DPI device - a poor decision in any case.

I cannot stress enough you should support and query the system accessibility fonts. I.e. people hard of reading will choose bigger fonts sizes, all of Apple's software and system supports it.

Usually in the iPad, you add more content/spaces but offer the same sizes. Buttons, as a rule can be bit bigger. That will define what looks good, widen margins on the iPad a bit, which I believe is already done.

Comment: Well its not the size of the button im concerned with but the text of the font. The point is i have a download progress view i created, within that view theres 2 labels. The percentage and overall_downloaded_bytes/all_bytes_needed_to_download. I have it workign by placing a check for if its either a phone or a pad. THen i set the font according to which device its on. I just thought there was some way of deciding the font size depending upon the screen size. Kinda like how i set the width and height of a view deoending upon the screen size

Comment: Also the problem is that its not legible or not. The problem is that on the iPad the font fits nicely within the bounds of the view but on the iPhone it doesnt. Im adding this view to either a tableview cell or collectionview cell and it fits within the bounds of the collectionview cell but not the tableview cell.

Comment: If you can upload a Sketch, I can give you better advice. Apple don't typically do this. IF you are using something like a header - you can make it extra large on iPad by using an autoscaling label and letting it shrink when constrained for space. The key point is Apple recommend using fonts that are ALWAYS legible.

Comment: Its not that they are not legible. Its just i want the font to fit into the size of the bounds perfectly. SO like i said when i set the font size for iPad its size of 38.0 if its in the iPhone its like size 16. What i do is i check if `UI_Userface_Idiom == iPad)` if so i set the font to 38 and so forth. What im trying to figure out is, is there a way to set the size of a font of a label by accessing one of the superview's properties.